# Angular - AWS Amplify amplify-authenticator crashes the form when the 'Code' I send is wrong

Tags: javascript, angular, aws-amplify

I have an `amplify-authenticator` form which I use to reset the password. If I enter a wrong code, I get a response from the API which says

> CodeMismatchException: Invalid verification code provided, please try again.

which is correct, but the entire form then freezes and I also get this message in the console of the browser:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'authAttributes')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'authAttributes')
> at actorDoneData (index.js:2:34774)

which points to `webpack:///node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui/dist/esm/index.js`

This is the code I have:

HTML

```
<amplify-authenticator [services]="services" initialState="resetPassword"></amplify-authenticator>
```

TS

```
    this.services = {
      async handleForgotPasswordSubmit(formData): Promise<void> {
        const { username, code, password } = formData;

        return Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit(username, code, password)
          .then(res => {
            //  Do something on success
          })
          .catch(err => {
            // The ERROR is here
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
    };
```

Please advise what can I do to avoid the form freeze problem. Thanks!

EDIT: It seems that if I remove the `.catch` from the promise, the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

function need to async await function. like below.

```
this.services = {
  async handleForgotPasswordSubmit(formData): Promise<void> {
    const { username, code, password } = formData;

    return await Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit(username, code, password)
      .then(res => {
        //  Do something on success
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // The ERROR is here
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
};
```